# Intersection of completion of subextension with algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a field, $char(K)=0$, complete w.t.r. to a discrete valuation and with perfect residue field of $char =p>0$.

Now consider a subextension $K\subset L\subset \bar{K}$ and denote by $C_K$ (resp. $\hat{L}$) the completion of $\bar{K}$ (resp. $L$). I would like to prove that 
\begin{equation*}
\hat{L}\cap \bar{K}= L.
\end{equation*}

If $L=\bar{K}^H$, where $H$ is a closed subgroup, i.e. $L/K$ Galois, one can show that $\hat{L}=C_K^H$ and thus

\begin{equation*}
\hat{L}\cap \bar{K}= C_K^H\cap \bar{K}=L
\end{equation*}
where the second equality follows from the fact that all elements in the intersection are invariant under $H$.

But how does one conclude the general case?

Comment: When you write "one can show" you mean with Ax-Sen-Tate, I presume? -- The first idea here is of course Krasner's Lemma, but I admit I cannot get it to work in generality, and I assume you have tried that already?

Comment: Yes, I mean Ax-Sen-Tate. The only obvious result is that the intersection is contained in the normal hull. For everything beyond that, I have a hard time concluding that something is in $L$.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bumping an old question. A colleague just rightly pointed out to me that "If $L=\bar K^H$, where $H$ is a closed subgroup, i.e. $L/K$ Galois, one can show ...", specifically the "i.e", is wrong; namely, *any* subextension $L$ is of that form; whereas $L/K$ Galois is equivalent to $H$ being a *normal* closed subgroup. Now I wonder in which case "one can show" what you have, and if that would make the question redundant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the rightfully pointing this out. Your argument seems to be somehwat sound: Consulting http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf, Prop. 2.1.2. yields at least a partial generalisation, but we do need that $H$ is open (so $L/K$ open). Actually this openess condition might not be necessary, I would need to think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with a friend, here is a somewhat complete (but not self-contained) proof of the statement. We want to prove the following

> **Theorem 1**
>   With the above notation, $\hat{L}\cap \bar{L}=L$.

We are going to do this in several steps. First let's state a more general version of Krasner's Lemma.

> **General Krasner's Lemma** Let $(K, |·|)$ be a non-archimedean valued field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ it's ring of of integers, $m$ its maximal ideal, $k = \mathcal{O}/m$ its residue field. Assume that $|·|$ extends to a separable closure $K^{sep}$. Then TFAE:
>
> 1. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is Henselian
> 2. Krasner's Lemma holds for $K$.

**Proof** I think one way to show this might be via a third criterion about uniqueness of valuations on finite extensions of $K$. I will leave this out for now, as this is not the main point.

Now we can state the main theorem:

> **Theorem 2** Let $K$ be as in Krasner's Lemma with $char(K)=0$ (i.e. I will not distinguish between algebraic and seperable closure anymore). Then TFAE:
>
> 1. $ \hat{K} \cap \bar{K}=K$
> 2. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is Henselian.

**Proof** "$1. \Rightarrow 2.$"
Let $f(x)\in \mathcal{O}_K[x]$ be a polynomial, such that there exists a $b\in \mathcal{O}_K$ satisfying $f(b) \equiv 0 \mod m_K $ and $f'(b)\not \equiv 0 \mod m_K$. We have to find a root $ \tilde{b} \in\mathcal{O}_K$ of $f(x)$.

To do this, consider $f(x)$ as a polynomial inside $\mathcal{O}_{\hat{K}}[x]$. As $\hat{K}$ is complete, $\mathcal{O}_{\hat{K}}$ is Henselian and thus we find a root $\tilde{b}\in \mathcal{O}_{\hat{K}}$. Now $\tilde{b}\in \bar{K}$, as it is a root of $f$, and $\tilde{b}\in \hat{K}$ by construction. Thus $\tilde{b}\in K$. As $\tilde{b}\in \mathcal{O}_{\hat{K}}$ we conclude that $\tilde{b}\in\mathcal{O}_{K}$.

"$2. \Rightarrow 1.$"

Let $a\in \hat{K}\cap\bar{K}$ with minimal polynomial $f(x)\in K[x]$ and other roots $a_2,...,a_n$. As $K$ is dense inside $\hat{K}$, we can find $b\in K$, such that $|b-a|<|b-a_i|$.  But by General Krasner's Lemma ($1. \Rightarrow 2.$) Krasner's Lemma holds and thus $K(a)\subset K(b)=K$, i.e. $a\in K$.

> **Lemma 3** $\mathcal{O}_L$ is Henselian.

**Proof** If $L/K$ is finite, this is clear, as $L$ is still complete. If $L/K$ is infinite, choosing a polynomial $f(x)\in \mathcal{O}_L[x]$, will always allow us to reduce to the finite field extension case (as there are only finitely many coefficents in $f$).

Thus Theorem 1 is proven by combining Lemma 3 with Theorem 2.

Comment: In the proof of $2 \Rightarrow 1$ for theorem 2, why can one find such a $b \in \hat K$?

Comment: I had a typo in there. Now it should be correct. To find such $b$ just note that we can find a sufficiently small ball (in $C_K$ ) around $a$, such that no $a_i$ is in this ball. But as $K$ is dense in $\hat{K}, we will definitely find such an element $b\in K$ inside that ball